# How to get String from Localization Strings in Android

Tags: android

> strings.xml

```
<string name="funny">Funny</string>
<string name="love">Love</string>
<string name="happy">Happy</string>
<string name="sad">Sad</string>
<string name="film">Film &amp; TV</string>
<string name="accident">Accident</string>
```

> strings.xml (pt)

```
<string name="funny">Engraçado</string>
<string name="love">Ame</string>
<string name="happy">Feliz</string>
<string name="sad">Triste</string>
<string name="film">Filme e TV</string>
<string name="accident">Acidente</string>
```

But, when I Use StringArray, then I want only from English String.xml

```
<string-array name="categories">

    <item>@string/funny</item>
    <item>@string/love</item>
    <item>@string/happy</item>
    <item>@string/sad</item>
    <item>@string/film</item>
    <item>@string/accident</item>

</string-array>
```

Comment: Just change the names in the strings.xml(pt) file, that way it won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for english .

```
        Locale myLocale = new Locale("en");
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

get String Array:

> String[] categories= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);

Comment: can you help that how to get string array after using this function ?

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya Once langauage is changed all lang is set no need separate work

Comment: yes, just mention string in language wise values folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programatically :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad  = "fa"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

for more visit [link](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2012/03/resources-based-on-localization.html)